# Can Winscp be installed on window server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, winscp

I want to know whether Winscp is free software? Can I install it on Window server2008?
    Which  version should I download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install it.

*WinSCP is free software: you can use it, redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
WinSCP is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but without any warranty; without even the implied warranty of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose. See the GNU General Public License for more details.*

You should download, for stability, the final stable version:

*WinSCP 4.3.7 installation package* from their website.

Comment: FWIW, I am currently logged on to a Win2008 R2 server, which has WinSCP version 4.3.2 installed.  It works fine, never had any issues with it.  As Lucas said, it's probably best to get the latest stable release.